# Increasing height when appending HTML

Tags: jquery, css, cordova

I am working with phonegap (build) and I am having problems when adding a variable number of divs inside a div container, as I would expect the container to increase its height accordingly, but it does not.

I have tried the  trick with no success. I have also tried different overflows and height:auto combinations with no success either.

I am now working in increasing the container height dynamically but, honestly I am pretty sure there must be a more elegant way to do so (I mean, this container might be inside some other container div, and so on and I can't imagine I must add this code for each one of them every time I need this behavior).

How do you guys deal with this (I guess really common) situation?

**Edit:**

I have found a solution based on Daniel's answer. Here is how I have dealt with it:

I work with three container divs and a list of a variable number of child divs:

- "page" div. Containing:

  - "content" div. Containing:

    - "categories" div. Containing:

      - A variable number of child divs

(I am sorry it is driving me crazy to add the code properly so I will include it as an image)

[image]

The explanation is:

- I define some variables to keep the original height of the three container divs, so later I can add them the necessary additional height depending on how many child divs are included.
- I check whether their values are empty so I assign them the value only the first time, so I don't keep adding height every time the user gets into the page.
- Each child div is 40px tall so I add this to a variable that accumulates the total height increase.

Finally I update the height of the containers and I get to see the whole content.

Anyway, my doubt is: Is it really necessary to do it every time I have to work with a dynamic height?
It is difficult for me to think there is no other way to get the containers increase their height accordingly a dynamic content.

Could anybody help me to understand this?

Comment: DIV elements should automatically expand to fill their contents unless it has `overflow` or `height` set, as you state you have tried. So, another thing to check would be to ensure that the dynamic elements are not `position`'ed or `float`'ed, which would take them out of the context of the container.

Comment: Please provide a code example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you describe you are adding div tags to another div tag like this:

```
<div id="container">
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     test
</div>
```

The extra div tags doesn't add additional height to the #container.

If this is what you are doing, you wont get extra height.

If you want to load more height inside the #container you can that with many different approaches.

1. With jQuery

   ```
   $("#container").css("height", "100px");
   ```
2. With CSS

   ```
   #container {
      height: 100px;
   }
   ```

If you want to add more height to a div#container you can do the following.

```
$("#container").click(function() {
    var height = $("#container").height();
    height = height + 10;
    $("#container").css({"height": height+"px"});
    /* do more here if you want :) */
});


<div id="container" style="background-color: red;">
   test
</div>
```

Comment: Ok I dealt with it by increasing manually the height of the container depending on the number of divs I had appended. This worked fine as I knew the height of each div. Now, I find myself in another limitation. In another view the height does not deppend on the number of fixed height divs but on a text which might have 10  or 10.000 chars. I try to retrieve the height of the div containing the text right after having appended it but it gives me 0 as a result (I assume its height increase has not yet been effective). How can I update the height in this situation???